# How to print certain elements of a list

Tags: python, list

How do I print certain elements of a list for example:

```
list1=["0","0","0","0","0","0","Element1","0","0","0","0"]
```

Is there any simple way to print only Element1 that specifies that you should not print out anything that is equal to 0.

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you please include more detail and provide a more thorough example?

Comment: example http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=list1%3D%5B%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%22Element1%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22,%220%22%5D%0Afor+item+in+list1%3A%0A++++if+item+!%3D+%220%22%3A%0A++++++++print(item)&mode=edit&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension or (as in this example) a generator expression to filter out the "0" items, and loop through the filtered list:

```
for item in (x for x in list1 if x != "0"):
    print(item)
```

This prints all items that are not "0".

Comment: Nice, but that's actually a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) not a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Often a gen exp is more efficient than a list comp, since it doesn't need to build a new list in memory; OTOH, it takes a little more time to set up a gen exp than a list comp. In this particular case, it probably doesn't make much difference which one you use.